# Why do I get "X is not a function" in the following recursive function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm using the following code to animate the opacity of an element:

```
      var opacity = 0 // starting opacity
      var step = 0.1 // step size
      var target = 1 // target value
      var time = 50 // delay in milliseconds
      // start timer loop, and record it's index
      var increaseOpacity = setInterval(function () {
        // assuming your selector works, set opacity
        $(`#pano-${index}`).attr({ opacity: opacity })
        // increment opacity by step size
        opacity += step
        // if we reached our target value, stop the timer
        if (opacity >= target) {
          clearInterval(increaseOpacity)
        }
      }, time)

      $('.pano').attr({ opacity: 0 })
      increaseOpacity()
```

It works. However, I get `Uncaught TypeError: increaseOpacity is not a function` every time I run the function.

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: Because it is not a `function`..It returns ID of the timer..

Comment: Also use `.css` to set any css property, not `.attr`

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy The element doesn't have `style` attribute only `opacity`: https://aframe.io/docs/components/material.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I get Uncaught TypeError: increaseOpacity is not a function
>   every time I run the function.

`increaseOpacity` is not a function object, it is an identifier for the timer so that `clearInterval` can **stop and clear** the timer later.

> Why is this and how to fix it?

You can simply remove this function call since it will be automatically invoked by `setInterval` method.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` return an interval index and not a function.

```
var increaseOpacity = function() {
  // ...
   if (opacity >= target) {
     clearInterval(increaseOpacityInterval);
   }
};

var increaseOpacityInterval = setInterval(increaseOpacity);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is just putting the setInterval in to a var
which means you defining a var to remember the time execution function

there is no need to call it cause it executes any way by the flow of your code
what you can use your new var increaseOpacity in the future is to clear this function setInterval if you want to disable it......

if you want this step to be called as a function all you need to do is

```
var increaseOpacity = function(){
    var SomeNewVarForInterval = setInterval(function () {
    // assuming your selector works, set opacity
    $(`#pano-${index}`).attr({ opacity: opacity })
    // increment opacity by step size
    opacity += step
    // if we reached our target value, stop the timer
    if (opacity >= target) {
      clearInterval(SomeNewVarForInterval)
    }
  }, time)
}
```

it is preferable that you will still remember the setInterval into a var if you would like to clear it somewhere in the future